# is it possible to add text to an php variable by clicking on an html checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I need to add an border to an image after I clicked on it. 
This is the php line I want to add text:

```
$class = 'cat-item cat-item-' . $category->term_id;
```

And this is my front-end code:

```
<li id="myButton" class="cat-item cat-item-27">
     <label>
         <input name="ofcategory[]" value="27" type="checkbox">
         Blue
     </label>
</li>
```

When clicking on the "Checkbox" which I made via css to an image I need to add an border to that image I am clicking on it

So just some toggleClass JavaScript is impossible right?

Is this even possible how I am thinking about it? Or do you may have a better idea?

Comment: Why impossible. Once its on the browser, where javascript runs, WordPress is all done with it

Comment: As long as the border doesn't have to be part of the image itself, you can use the power of CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use PHP to handle events such as *clicks* as it is a *server-side* language and the *client-side* is handled by your browser. Here are 2 solutions for what you're trying to achieve:

Using **CSS** [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) pseudo-class selector:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked {
    border: 4px solid red;
}
```

Using **JS** and [`element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) (assuming you declared a `.border` class before):

```
var input = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');

input.addEventListener("click", function () {
    input.classList.toggle('border');
});
```

---

*I would recommend to use the CSS solution, which will be shorter to code (it can be considered a good practice to avoid doing things in JavaScript you can do in CSS).*